# Can we run perl and python cgi web portal from same server/box

Tags: python, perl, cgi

I have a box where we are running a internal web page build on perl-cgi. My knowledge is little limited about coding. but I want to run some pages built on python cgi. Technically is it possible to run both perl+python cgi on same server without doing much configuration change

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's actually very easy. Because `cgi` doesn't care what language it's written it - it's just a script that the web server runs on demand, and passes parameters.

You can even use compiled C as your cgi language if you want.

All you need to do is be able to read the local environment (and pretty much every language can) and read `STDIN` - and pretty much every language can.

You can comfortably run `perl` and `python` scripts along side each other - the server simply doesn't care.

To get more complicated, you might want to preload/prefork your cgi scripts, and then it starts to be a *little* more complicated to use arbitrary languages.

But for a basic run-on-demand cgi script, anything will suffice.

Comment: You may add that a CGI program needs to be executable. In linux it means a correct *shebang* for scripts and the executable permission. Also, try to use a library to help you with all the parameter passing and HTML generation. For Perl, at least [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html). For Python something like [cgitb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html).